# Dynamic hasMany relationship in Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to have a dynamic relationship based on a class name, which is stored as a property on a far related model.

There are lots of different class names so I don't want to make lots of relationships. It's a bit complicated but it has to be this way.

```
function subjectvotes() {    
    $className = $this->masterCourse->subject->class_name;
    return $this->hasMany($class)->orderBy('value');
}
```

Trying to do it this way won't work mid-query because it doesn't always have the 'child' model information yet (as `->get()` hasn't been run). Another issue with this is it's running the same `$this->parent->grandparent` query every time — not ideal.

Before I start the relationship query, I can run this to get the class name and table name respectively:

```
$className = $masterCourseModel->subject->class_name;
$tableName = ( new $className )->getTable();
```

But how to feed this into the relationship I'm not yet sure:

```
$masterCourseModel->studentCourse()->with('subjectvotes')->get();
```

Without creating a lot of relationships for each possible class, how do I feed the `$className` in to create a dynamic hasMany relationship, or can I do this by adding a new query scope and feeding in the `$tableName` or `$className` that way?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can you write more snippet, or just get some real entities (like sports, football, football player, etc) as example?

Comment: Did you consider `Polymorphic Relations` to solve your problem? You cant eager load dynamic relational data.


https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Thanks for the replies - I did consider polymorphism, but the related model that stores the model information is 2 relationships away.

Comment: @Chay22 I've made an edit. It's hard to explain, but there is a mastercourse, which students can make their own versions of, and then vote on whatever the subject is within their course. The course is related to the parent though, otherwise this information would be repeated. But we need to know the subject for the relationship of the studentCourse (their version of the masterCourse). Does that make more sense?

Comment: Well, sorry, I still can't get your current implementation. Might need to know the classes you're relating to. But anyways, to prevent from running the same query everytime, you can create a static property as a cache to store the result of one or more queries just like `static::$mutatorCache` for  example. As static property will hold any values defined until current script execution die, doesnt it?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea to use a static property on the model - thanks for that suggestion - I'll do that for the time being to save additional queries. The problem is it will only work with a ->load('subjectvotes') as then we already have the results of studentCourse. i.e. it won't work with ->studentCourse()->with('subjectvotes')